# Ruby Twitter, Retrieving Full Tweet Text

Tags: ruby, api, twitter, rubygems

I'm using the Ruby Twitter gem to retrieve the full text of a tweet.

I first tried this, and as you can see the text was truncated.

```
[5] pry(main)> t = client.status(782845350918971393)
=> #<Twitter::Tweet id=782845350918971393>
[6] pry(main)> t.text
=> "A #Gameofthrones fan? Our #earlybird Dublin starter will get you 
touring the GOT location in 2017
#traveldealls… (SHORTENED URL WAS HERE)"
```

Then I tried this:

```
[2] pry(main)> t = client.status(782845350918971393, tweet_mode: 'extended')
=> #<Twitter::Tweet id=782845350918971393>
[3] pry(main)> t.full_text
=>
[4] pry(main)> t.text
=>
```

Both the text and full text are empty when I use the `tweet_mode: 'extended'` option.

I also tried editing the bit of the gem that makes the request, the response was the same.

`perform_get_with_object("/1.1/statuses/show/#{extract_id(tweet)}.json?tweet_mode=extended", options, Twitter::Tweet)`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a workaround I found helpful:

> Below is the way I am handling this issue ATM. Seems to be working. I am using both Streaming (with Tweetstream) and REST APIs.

```
status = @client.status(1234567890, tweet_mode: "extended")

if status.truncated? && status.attrs[:extended_tweet]
  # Streaming API, and REST API default
  t = status.attrs[:extended_tweet][:full_text]
else
  # REST API with extended mode, or untruncated text in Streaming API
  t = status.attrs[:text] || status.attrs[:full_text]
end
```

From https://github.com/sferik/twitter/pull/848#issuecomment-329425006

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much!